# readlines is showing up empty after creating file

Tags: python, readlines

I am looking to create a file then read the values I just put into it and put those values into a list.  I use readlines to do so, however I get the "list assignment index out of range" error which tells me that its not reading the file.

here is my code:

```
import os

class open_saved_file():

    def __init__(self):
        self.path = os.getcwd()
        self.path_extension = "/Saved_Paths"
        self.file_extension = "/Paths.txt"
        self.paths = []

    def test_path(self):

        test_bool = os.path.exists(self.path+self.path_extension)
#1) path does not exist
        if not test_bool:
            print "The start folder does not exist, let's create it"
            os.makedirs(self.path+self.path_extension)
            print "just made file, now make Paths.txt"
            of = open(self.path+self.path_extension+self.file_extension, 'w+')
            print "Lets add 4 dummy lines of code"
            i = 0
            while i < 4:
                of.write("dummy\n")
                i = i+1
            print "just added four lines of dummy"
            of.close()
            print "lets test"
            self.read_lines_into_list()
            return self.paths
#2) path and file exist
        else:
            print "The start folder did exist, yay!"
            print "lets open it and put its value into paths list"
            self.read_lines_into_list()
            return self.paths

    def read_lines_into_list(self):
        of = open(self.path+self.path_extension+self.file_extension)
        lines = of.readlines()
        self.paths[0] = lines[0][:-1]
        self.paths[1] = lines[1][:-1]
        self.paths[2] = lines[2][:-1]
        self.paths[3] = lines[3][:-1]
        print "lets test if all the values went in"
        j = 0
        while j < 4:
            print self.paths[j]
            i = i+1
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that the file was actually created at the location you specified?

Comment: yes i have.  It is created before the error is thrown

Comment: Include the error in your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error occurs not because `lines` is empty, but because `self.paths` is. Instead of:

```
self.paths[0] = lines[0][:-1]
```

Use `append()`:

```
self.paths.append(lines[0][:-1])
```

You're also going to get an error in your `while` loop because you're doing a `i = i+1` when your loop variable is `j`. You can simply replace `i` with `j`, or even better, use a `for` loop:

```
for path in self.paths:
    print path
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also add a call to os.path.isfile to validate the file exists.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the modified version of the code.

```
import os
class OpenSavedFile():
def __init__(self):
    self.path = os.getcwd()
    self.path_extension = "/Saved_Paths"
    self.file_extension = "/Paths.txt"
    self.paths = []

def test_path(self):
    test_bool = os.path.exists(self.path+self.path_extension)
    if not test_bool:
        print "The start folder does not exist, let's create it"
        os.makedirs(self.path+self.path_extension)
        print "just made file, now make Paths.txt"
        of = open(self.path+self.path_extension+self.file_extension, 'w+')
        print "Lets add 4 dummy lines of code"
        i = 0
        while i < 4:
            of.write("dummy\n")
            i = i+1
        print "just added four lines of dummy"
        of.close()
        print "lets test"
        self.read_lines_into_list()
        return self.paths
    else:
        print "The start folder did exist, yay!"
        print "lets open it and put its value into paths list"
        self.read_lines_into_list()
        return self.paths

def read_lines_into_list(self):
    of = open(self.path+self.path_extension+self.file_extension)
    lines = of.readlines()
    # lines is not empty 
    # remove the comment below and see
    # print lines
    for line in lines:
        self.paths.append(line[:-1]) # paths is an empty list so append the contents
    print "lets test if all the values went in"
    j = 0
    while j < 4:
        print self.paths[j]
        j += 1 # this is not i += 1

op = OpenSavedFile()
op.test_path()
```

Comment: The author's original code does not iterate the list infinitely, so this is incorrect. Upon reaching `i = i+1`, an `UnboundLocalError` is thrown and the program exits.

Comment: Yeah, j's value is 0 throughout the iterations so an `UnboundLocalError` will be thrown.